# What does this quote mean: "Why is this thus? And what is the reason for this thusness?

Tags: quotes

In the movie 'Lincoln', Abraham Lincoln portrayed by Daniel Day-Lewis says this to Representative Ashley:

***"Why for instance is this thus, and what is the reason for this thusness."***

What does that even mean?

Comment: Why is it like that? And for what reason is it like that?

Comment: I think it is a bit of statesman's licence, rather like some things attributed to Churchill such as *...up with which I will not put*.

Comment: As Josh says, for the meaning. But the tone is contemptuous: Lincoln is using assonance to reduce what he is asking about to complex gibberish. It's an angry and witty retort. He was a great orator, Lincoln...

Comment: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Artemus_Ward

Comment: Why "even"? What is the reason for this evening?

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thusness#:%7E:text=1%20%3A%20the%20condition%20of%20being,2%20%3A%20suchness%20sense%202) simply defines ***thusness*** as

> the condition of being thus

So in his rhetorical way of speaking, Lincoln meant:

> Why is this (*situation*) thus (*in such a state*), and what is the reason for this thusness (*for this state*).

Answer (score -2):

Lincoln was re-quoting Artemus Ward.  James Joyce does it too (with paraphrase), in 'Portrait of the Artist': "if it is thus, I ask emphatically whence comes this thusness."

Comment: Provides color, but does not answer the question.

Comment: I think may is a good *context* to add to an answer, but it is missing the original quote referenced and an explanation, so it does not answer the original question. Quite interesting to note, though!